# jquery virtual keyboard shuffle

Tags: jquery, virtual-keyboard

I have tried virtual keyboard shuffle by referring the given url

[1]: https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/docs/scramble.html. Here keyboard has shuffled on every click while opening.But it has to shuffle on click of any numbers.Pls see the below code and suggest me where i made a mistake.

```
$('#hex').keyboard({
    openOn   : null,
    stayOpen : true,
    lockInput: true,
    layout: 'custom',
    customLayout: {
        'normal' : [

            '1 2 3 4 ',
            '5 6 7 8',
            '9 0 {bksp}',
            '{a} {c} '
        ]
    },
    maxLength : 20,
    restrictInput : true, // Prevent keys not in the displayed keyboard from being typed in
    // include lower case characters (added v1.25.7)
    restrictInclude : 'a b c d e f',
    useCombos : false, // don't want A+E to become a ligature
    acceptValid: true,
    validate: function(keyboard, value, isClosing){
        // only make valid if input is 6 characters in length
        return value.length === 20;
    }
});

$('#hex').click(function(){
    var kb = $('#hex').getkeyboard();

    if ( kb.isOpen ) {

        kb.close();
    } else {
        kb.reveal();

    }
});

 $('#hex')  .keyboard()
        .addScramble({
            byRow         : false,     // randomize by row, otherwise randomize all keys
            randomizeOnce : false,     // if false, randomize every time the keyboard opens


        });
```

By this code the numbers are shuffled while the virtual keyboard has opened. But i need to shuffle the numbers on each and every click numbers by opening.

Comment: Please clarify... you want the keys to scramble *after* every input?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. yes the keys have to scramble after every input of numbers.

Comment: Ahh, so you want to torture your users ;) LOL... I've opened a new issue (https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/522) I'll try to get to it soon.

Comment: Ya sure thats the requirement. Thank u

Comment: Keyboard v1.26.18 is now available with a scramble on every input option - see [last example on this page](https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/docs/scramble.html).